# ¿Como fusionar tres listas en una y ordenar sus valores en el proceso?

Tags: python

Tengo 3 listas que las quiero fusionar y ordenar luego para que queden en un sola (*salida*) tomando de las tres el primer valor y concatenarlo y asi hasta finalizar.

este el code que fui haciendo ...

```
lis1 = [(10,2), (23,4)]

lis2 = [(5,16) , (70,8)]

lis3 = [(44,3), (9,90)]

salida =[]

for i in range(Len(lis1):   

   salida.append(list(lis1[i] + lis2[i] + lis3[i]))

   
print(salida)
```

Cuya salida es ....

```
[[10, 2, 5, 16, 44, 3], [23, 4, 70, 8, 9, 90]]
```

Ahora necesito que las **listas internas** queden ordenadas pero no se como hacerlo al iterar en el bucle. Lo que me deberia quedar asi ...

[[2, 3, 5, 10, 16, 44], [4, 8, 9, 23, 70, 90]]

Pongo este codigo y me da Error
salida.append(list.Sort(lis1[i] + lis2[i] + lis3[i]))

Comment: `sorted(lista)`? Y luego juntarlas?

Comment: lo que pasa es que las listas traen tuplas lis3 = [(44,3), (9,90)] y si pongo lis3.Sort() no lo ordena

Comment: Escribiste sort, todo en minusculas?

Comment: si si aca lo puse mal. use sort no sorted

Comment: salida.append(l1.sort([i]) +l2.sort([i]))) asi puse y tampoco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasar cada tupla final a `sorted` (y obviar `list`, ya que `sorted` devuelve una lista).

```py
lis1 = [(10,2), (23,4)]
lis2 = [(5,16) , (70,8)]
lis3 = [(44,3), (9,90)]

salida =[]

for i in range(len(lis1)):
    salida.append(sorted(lis1[i] + lis2[i] + lis3[i]))

print(salida)

#> [[2, 3, 5, 10, 16, 44], [4, 8, 9, 23, 70, 90]]
```

Comment: GENIAL !! eso solucionó mi problema. Muchas gracias @Nuno